# why python list append not working in my code?

Tags: python

I am trying to append multiple items in a single list. here is my code:

```
for i in amenities_extras:
             amenities_extras = i.text
             print("###amenities_extras: ",amenities_extras)
```

the result which I am getting:

```
###amenities_extras:  Accessible
###amenities_extras:  Bar Tab
###amenities_extras:  Coffee / Tea
###amenities_extras:  Dance Floor
###amenities_extras:  External Music
###amenities_extras:  Filtered Water
###amenities_extras:  Furniture Hire
###amenities_extras:  Inhouse Catering
###amenities_extras:  Microphone
###amenities_extras:  Natural light
###amenities_extras:  Outdoor Space
###amenities_extras:  Parking
###amenities_extras:  Restroom
###amenities_extras:  Security
###amenities_extras:  Speakers
###amenities_extras:  TV
###amenities_extras:  WiFi
```

here I am trying this code for put all items in a single list:

```
for i in amenities_extras:
             amenities_extras_list =[] 
             amenities_extras = i.text
             print("###amenities_extras: ",amenities_extras_list.append(amenities_extras))
```

I am getting this result:

```
###amenities_extras:  None
###amenities_extras:  None
###amenities_extras:  None
###amenities_extras:  None............
....................................
..........................................
```

why it's not appending all items like this `['Accessible','Bar Tab','Dance Floor','WiFi']`

Comment: `append` doesn't return anything useful, just None. It modifies the list in place. You probably want to declare that list outside of the loop, otherwise you're making a new list and putting 1 element in it on each iteration, only to overwrite it on the next iteration. `amenities_extras = ...` also overwrites the list that's being looped over. Or just use `[x.text for x in amenities_extras]`.

Comment: `append` does not return a value.

Comment: You are emptying the list every time through the loop.  And since `amenities_extras` already contains the list, what are you really trying to do here?

Comment: Thanks all...the problem was my list in  inside for loop.

Comment: BTW this `amenities_extras = i.text` in beginning of loop is very confusing since you iterate over `amenities_extras` it is not clear what was your intent. It would be better to avoid such variable smashing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two primarily errors from your code (apart from the bad code choice),

```
for i in amenities_extras:
             amenities_extras_list =[] # This will make the list back to zero.
             amenities_extras = i.text
             print("###amenities_extras: ",amenities_extras_list.append(amenities_extras))
```

Perhaps you meant,

```
amenities_extras_list =[] 
for i in amenities_extras:
             
             amenities_extras = i.text
             print("###amenities_extras: ",amenities_extras_list.append(amenities_extras))
```

And `append` does not return value, this is the final code,

```
amenities_extras_list = [] # Or use list()
for i in amenities_extras:
             amenities_extras = i.text
             amenities_extras_list.append(amenities_extras)
             print("###amenities_extras: ", amenities_extras_list[-1])
```

(Edited thanks to @juanpa.arrivillaga)

Comment: `amenities_extras_list[i]` nope, that won't work. You'd need `i` to be the zerod count of the iteration, e.g. using `enumerate`, but instead, you can just do `amenities_extras_list[-1]`

Comment: Wait, I forgot that `i` is not an integer....